# Android - How to automate view creation?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

[image]

I am developing a data collection app. I have lots of such questions and different sets of options for answers. I could create an activity for each question. But that will be a very inefficient method as I have over 50 such questions.

What do I have to do to dynamically generate and populate the checkboxes? It'll be a lot easier if I can just specify the number of checkboxes, a String array holding the options and dynamically generate the checkboxes in Java.

Will I be needing CustomViews?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches possible:

1. Create an activity that contains an array of arrays to hold your data and loop over it adding checkboxes to the layout.
2. Create a separate layout for each question and store your data in tags associated with checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many checkboxes you need, you could always just add them to a layout programmatically. For example, if you get a String array of options passed in through the Intent, you can do this:

```
String[] answers = ... // get from Intent extras
LinearLayout container = findViewById...
int numCheckboxes = answers.length;
for (int i = 0; i < numCheckboxes; i++) {
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this /*context*/);
    checkbox.setText(answers[i]);
    container.addView(checkbox);
}
```

The finer details that you may have to deal with are knowing which checkbox is checked. You might try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCheckboxes; i++) {
    ...
    checkbox.setTag(i);
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(checkedChangedListener);
    ...
}
...
boolean[] responses;
...
private OnCheckedChangedListener checkedChangedListener = new OnCheckedChangedListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Object tag = buttonView.getTag();
        if (tag instanceOf Integer) {
            Integer index = (Integer) tag;
            responses[index] = isChecked;
        }
    }
};
```